# Getting error headers with urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I need to send a PUT request to a web service and get some data out of error headers that is the expected result of the request. The code goes like this:

```
Request = urllib2.Request(destination_url, headers=headers)
Request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'

try:
   Response = urllib2.urlopen(Request)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
   print 'Error code: ', e.code
   print e.read()
```

I get Error 308 but response is empty and I'm not getting any data out of HTTPError. Is there a way to get HTTP headers while getting an HTTP error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`e` has undocumented `headers` and `hdrs` properties that contains the HTTP headers sent by the server.

By the way, 308 is [not a valid HTTP status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.8).

Comment: Thanks! It works! I know 308 is not valid but Youtube uses it for checking the upload status.